# In Multiplayer, if I attack all other players for lethal, who loses first?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Is it simultaneous, like 1st me > several tied 2nd places? Or is there a sequence to it. I know 802.6. Combat damage is assigned in APNAP order. Other than that, the combat damage step proceeds just as in a two-player game. See rule 510, “Combat Damage Step.” under "Attack multiple players" is a thing, but does that just mean that turn player deals all his damage first, or is there a sequence to the order in which players lose to lethal damage?

Answer (score 4):

**All combat damage happens simultaneously.**

> **510.2.** Second, **all combat damage that’s been assigned is dealt simultaneously**. This turn-based action doesn’t use the stack. No player has the chance to cast spells or activate abilities between the time combat damage is assigned and the time it’s dealt.

802.6 is simply explaining a slight difference to 510.1:

> **510.1.** First, the active player announces how each attacking creature assigns its combat damage, then the defending player announces how each blocking creature assigns its combat damage. This turn-based action doesn’t use the stack.

So "defending player" in this case means each of the opponents being attacked, in APNAP order.

However, the premise of your question may be flawed. There is no "second place" in magic. It doesn't matter which player loses first, or if it is simultaneous. If I kill opponent A on turn 5, and then kill opponent B on turn 6, opponent B isn't "second place" while opponent A is "third place". They are simply both players who did not win the game.

Comment: Then, say for the purposes of an event, where placement may be tied to rewards, it would then fall to the determination of the TO, since there is not a precedent for it within the game's rule set?

Comment: @Porkchopz, I believe there are no sanctioned multi-player tournaments (except for 2-headed giant), so tieing rewards to placement doesn't happen. If you're asking about an unsanctioned tournament with non-standard rules, you'd have to ask the tournament organizers about their rules; we can't possibly know what they are.

Comment: @Porkchopz For a tournament, unofficial or not, I would expect multiple games would be getting played; so I would think of second place in terms of winning the second-most matches; or only losing to the first-place player, etc. But it would be up to the TO. I don't think "last player to lose a specific game" is a great way to determine it; because players may play differently if they have something to gain by simply not being the first player to die.

Comment: FWIW there have been 4 player commander side events at GPs where prizes have been determined by placement so the situation described in OP isn't exactly impossible. I'm not sure how they dealt with "ties for second" as it didn't come up in the games I was watching.

Comment: @GendoIkari I have been in EDH events before where the order mattered. in some cases it's elimination, last place is removed or top two move on, so place matters, in others, or the final round, it's simply prize distribution based on your result in that round alone.